# Arrays not filling properly AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I wrote an array, where, when a hittest occurs, a number should be pushed into the array. However, when I use myArray.push, it enters the number, and when i call myArray.push again, instead of entering the number again and having 2 numbers in my array, it just enters the number in the same spot. So, if i use trace(myArray.length), no matter how many times it has pushed, it keeps saying I have 1 number stored.
This is my code:

```
if (hitTestObject(target.hit)) { 
    //pushes a number into an array
    myArray.push();

    //checks array length
    if (myArray.length == 3) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

I've tried numbers, strings, and Math.random() in the parameters for myArray.push(), but I always get the same result of only having 1 item in my array. 
For reference, this is how I wrote my variable for it:

```
 public var myArray:Array = new Array();
```

Comment: You need to post more code.  Most likely you are recreating the array each time, but can't tell from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to push something into the array. Try:

```
myArray.push(myArray.length);
```

However, it looks like you'd be better off just incrementing a number rather than creating an array. An array is a container of objects to be later referenced. So, unless you need to track that the third object in the array is in fact '2'...the array is useless. Try creating a number and increment the variable each time. Like this:

```
// Declared outside of the function
var integer:int = 0;

//
if (hitTestObject(target.hit)) { 
    integer = integer + 1;
    // likewise you could use ++integer or integer++;

    if (integer == 3) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I actually push the length of the array into the array?

Comment: Okay, so instead of a number, I just passed int into myArray.push, and that worked, so instead of myArray.push(1);, I had myArray.push(int).    Is that correct, or is my code working from a miraculous bug?

Comment: The length of the array will increment automatically with each push. Of course, the length is zero(0) at first, but each time you hit this chunk of code, that length will increase. Essentially giving you an array looking like [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,etc.].

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you are not actually pushing anything into the array.

The correct syntax is :

```
myArray.push(something);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've used different numbers, strings, and Math.random, like I said above

Comment: You have zero idea what you are doing. Would be best for you to take a step back and learn about arrays, and what I have said will not be a mystery to you. It's likely that your code is littered with similar other misunderstandings, so this process isn't going to help you much, if at all.

Comment: Yeha, I guess you're right. I learn best through trial and error, so I guess that's what I was trying to do, but I'll go back and relearn some stuff.